# Groovy - How to split a String containing a number of FileNames but some of them contains spaces?

Tags: string, groovy, split

How to split a string containing a number of file names (including names containing spaces)?

**Example String:**

```
randomFolderNameA/path/to/file1.java randomFolderNameB/path/to/file2.sql randomFolderNameC/path/to/file3 with space.xml file4 with space.sql
```

**Expected output:**

```
randomFolderNameA/path/to/file1.java
randomFolderNameB/path/to/file2.sql
randomFolderNameC/path/to/file3 with space.xml
file4 with space.sql
```

Comment: As an endeavour like this will always be tricky or erroneous: what is the source of those names and can't you let upstream separate them better?

Comment: I understand. This is actually an output from Jenkin's Last Changes plugin. We have logged a ticket there. But this is a work around for time being.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all your paths are absolute, you can use look-ahead assertion in your regex:

```
def text = "/path/to/file1.java /path/to/file2.sql /path/to/file3 with space.xml"
println text.split(" (?=/)")
```

And that outputs `[/path/to/file1.java, /path/to/file2.sql, /path/to/file3 with space.xml]`

Taht regex splits the string on a space followed by a `/`

---

**EDIT:** For the updated example, it's possible to look at extensions in file names, although you'd need to carefully consider what your input can include:

```
def text = "randomFolderNameA/path/to/file1.java randomFolderNameB/path/to/file2.sql randomFolderNameC/path/to/file3 with space.xml file4 with space.sql"

println text.split("(?<=\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}) ")
```

That outputs the following, as expected:

```
[randomFolderNameA/path/to/file1.java, 
 randomFolderNameB/path/to/file2.sql, 
 randomFolderNameC/path/to/file3 with space.xml, 
 file4 with space.sql]
```

But as noted above, you need to be sure that paths only include file names and the extension regex is valid (I used "a dot followed by 1 to 4 alpha-numeric characters")

Comment: sorry updated my question. The sample string I provided was very misleading.

Comment: Does that mean you have relative paths in the original list? Can you add a real example?

Comment: @Dinesh I don't see a way to split paths from just the input string (there's no reliable delimiter). You'll surely have to change the code that generates the string to make it use a delimiter (such as `,`) or to include absolute paths (in which case you'd be able to use this answer's solution). Or do you want to use extensions in file names?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't control the code its part of a 3rd party api. And Yeah, Is it possible to split the strings after the file extensions. Also note the files can have any extension. But they will certainly have one.

Comment: @Dinesh I've edited the post. But please note the remark about the regex for extensions

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You're awesome!